# Problem exporting .svg to .pdf using inkscape

Tags: inkscape, pdf, svg

I have a problem when exporting (or "saving as") some .svg files into .pdf using Inkscape. For some reason, some random "small" parts of the pictures are not rendered. Is there a way to "force" inkscape to export everything, is there a solution another software I could use instead ?

Here is an example file:
svg file [here](https://mega.nz/#!VM9lDJBD!7DI_c_3Lx7gny7N9fE9gMPKeU1kd75z4E30zxqzTFaY) and pdf file [here](https://mega.nz/#!9YslHKrD!oNcbXdjGVGnLDbkf9ytaXomFLXf8RSQFypTzClelOCQ). The round bits of the notes are not rendered in the pdf.

(I use the latest version of Inkscape (0.91))

Comment: Hi HcN, welcome to GDSE and thanks for your question. If you want to know more about the site, please see the [help] or ping one of us in the [chat] once your reputation is sufficient (20). Keep contributing and enjoy the site!

Comment: I fail to reproduce your problem with the linked SVG, which makes it very likely that we are talking about a bug here, which is off-topic here, since we are plainly not the right place to address such issues.

Comment: It may not be a bug, as they are aspects of svg files that pdf do not like, like transparency. I solved another export to pdf problem turning the object transparency to a colour transparency. I was expecting something similar for this case. What OS and version of inkscape do you use ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inkscape's pdf generation is usually very good so I wouldn't go complicating matters with additional software/tools.

Sometimes a file benefits from the objects being ungrouped. Sometimes you'll find that a slightly open object won't export happily and sometimes flipping the direction of a path helps.

I've had a quick play with your file and I'm stumped as to why it won't export the simple ovals.  If I were you I'd quickly re-add these elements as a test oval I added exported fine.

I notice that you're using filter effects - bear in mind that these result in non vector elements which may cause you trouble.  They get rasterised at a resolution that you set on pdf export.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. I was expecting this error to be from something that I have missed concerning exporting svg to pdf, but it seems to be something deeper. Anyway, I fixed my problem redoing the notes. If it cannot be easily helped, this is the only solution left. Thanks a lot indeed !